# Prevent anchor behaviour on click on DOM generated element inside anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dom, preventdefault

An arrow ***button*** for moving a *slider* ended up inside an ***anchor*** element.
Now when the ***button*** is clicked the ***anchor*** link is activated.

The ***button*** is part of a dinamically created content on page load by *3rd party slider scripts.*

Need to keep the ***anchor*** to link to the post. And prevent the ***anchor*** from working, only when the ***button*** is clicked on.

By the way it´s meant for Wordpress.

Thank you.

```
var jq=jQuery.noConflict();

jq(document).ready(function(){ 

   jq(document).on("click", 'button.next' , function() {
      jq('a').defaultPrevented();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jq(document).on("click", 'button.next' , function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
   });
```